# How to display whole words as a different symbol?

Tags: display

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6jfrrwR10k&feature=youtu.be&t=1087) (time-linked, only a few seconds) the word `function` is displayed as *`f`*, but can still be edited so the underlying text remains as-is.

How can this be done in emacs? (using plugins or built in features).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prettify-symbols-mode comes with emacs; [here's a blog post about it](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/08/25/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-prettify-symbols-mode/). You need to add the substitution to `prettify-symbols-alist` in whatever mode you want it in. Here's an example for javascript-mode:

```
(add-hook 'javascript-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
          (push '("function" . ?λ) prettify-symbols-alist)))
```

and then `M-x` `prettify-symbols-mode`

To avoid having to set this manually, it can be enabled globally from your init file:

```
(global-prettify-symbols-mode t)
```

Comment: You could enable the mode from the hook too. Is that better or worse ?

Comment: Note that [indentation, etc. will be against the *prettified* version of the text](http://endlessparentheses.com/using-prettify-symbols-in-clojure-and-elisp-without-breaking-indentation.html), which could be problematic.

Answer (score 3):

While the current answer is useful, this example shows how to set many characters at once and enable globally when in graphical mode.

```
(when local-cfg/use-prettify-symbols
  (add-hook
   'rust-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     (setq
      prettify-symbols-alist
      '(
        ("fn"         . ?ƒ)
        ("Fn"         . ?)
        ("->"         . ?→)
        ("=>"         . ?⇒)
        (">="         . ?≥)
        ("<="         . ?≤)
        ("=="         . ?≡)
        ("!="         . ?≢)
        (".."         . ?‥)
        ("..."        . ?…)

        ; ("*"          . ?×)
        ; ("/"          . ?÷)
        )
      )
     )
   )
  )
```

Comment: If you have multiple frames some of them graphic some other not then this will not work completely as expected. for example if you're using the emacs daemon, I think the hook will not be added.